# Downloading Images From Server As Binary To Android

Tags: c#, android, sql, file

I am currently storing images in an SQL server database having type image. i have built an android app that retrieves these images by calling on a c# web service that fetches the image from the database, encode it in Base64 and send it to the android app. in the app level, i decode it and change it to image successfully. my concern is that this call downloads the data once and not in chunks and may result in timeouts in case of multiple images. so can anyone suggest an alternative? should i store the images as physical files and not in the database and use download manager to retrieve them? any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: For that can you used Picasso library, Picasso.with(context).load(URL).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).into(imageview);

Comment: but to use this, the image can't be stored in the database right?

Comment: Yes, want to store image in local database?

Comment: that is what i am currently doing. but is it a better solution to store them physically? and use picasso?

Comment: Picasso is used for load image from server and display into image view..

Comment: can i save them in a directory on the phone using this as well?

Comment: No, for that need to write code to store image into directory..

Comment: Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
            /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

            //Set it in the ImageView
            theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        }
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88066/discussion-between-patel-hiren-and-rashad-z).